# SQL Query to show products in and out in one output

Tags: sql

If I have 2 tables:

```
Purchases
-----------------------------------
date          product_id        qty
-----------------------------------
2023-07-01    10                  2
2023-07-03    10                  2
2023-07-05    10                  1


Sales
-----------------------------------
date          product_id        qty
-----------------------------------
2023-07-02    10                  1
2023-07-03    10                  1
2023-07-06    10                  1
```

And I would like to have an output like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
date          product_id        in        out
---------------------------------------------
2023-07-01    10                  2         -
2023-07-02    10                  -         1
2023-07-03    10                  2
2023-07-03    10                  -         1
2023-07-05    10                  1         -
2023-07-06    10                  -         1
```

Is it possible to achieve this with an SQL Query?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just unified them using `UNION ALL`:

```
   SELECT   [date],
            [product_id],
            [qty]           AS [qty_in],
            NULL            AS [qty_out]
    FROM    Purchases

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  [date],
            [product_id],
            NULL            AS [qty_in],
            [qty]           AS [qty_out]
    FROM    Sales
```

it will result this:

| date | product_id | qty_in | qty_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-01 | 10 | 2 | NULL |
| 2023-07-03 | 10 | 2 | NULL |
| 2023-07-05 | 10 | 1 | NULL |
| 2023-07-02 | 10 | NULL | 1 |
| 2023-07-03 | 10 | NULL | 1 |
| 2023-07-06 | 10 | NULL | 1 |

---

Take in mind you can also group them by date and product, like this:

```
SELECT  T.[date],
        T.[product_id],
        SUM([qty_in])       AS  [in],
        SUM([qty_out])      AS  [out]
FROM
(
    SELECT  [date],
            [product_id],
            [qty]           AS [qty_in],
            NULL            AS [qty_out]
    FROM    Purchases

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  [date],
            [product_id],
            NULL            AS [qty_in],
            [qty]           AS [qty_out]
    FROM    Sales
)   AS      T

GROUP BY    T.[date],
            T.[product_id]
```

in this example:

- the 2 sources were unified using `UNION ALL`
- putting all Purchases under column "qty_in" of the unified source
- putting all Sales under column "qty_out" of the unified source
- the new source query was used as a alias "T", using wrapping `FROM`
- summing all "qty_in" and all "qty_out"
- grouping by each column which should appear using `GROUP BY`

| date | product_id | in | out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-01 | 10 | 2 | NULL |
| 2023-07-02 | 10 | NULL | 1 |
| 2023-07-03 | 10 | 2 | 1 |
| 2023-07-05 | 10 | 1 | NULL |
| 2023-07-06 | 10 | NULL | 1 |

Answer (score 2):

Use "UNION ALL" for tables,

```
select ... from A
UNION ALL 
select ... from B
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the UNION ALL operator to combine the rows from the "Purchases" and "Sales" tables, and then grouping the result by the date and product_id columns.

```
   SELECT 
        date,
        product_id,
        SUM(in_qty) AS `in`,
        SUM(out_qty) AS `out`
   FROM (
       SELECT date, product_id, qty AS in_qty, NULL AS out_qty
       FROM Purchases
       UNION ALL
       SELECT date, product_id, NULL AS in_qty, qty AS out_qty
    FROM Sales
    ) AS combined
    GROUP BY date, product_id
    ORDER BY date;
```

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the preferred output, you can do in this way

```
SELECT date, product_id,
       IF(SUM(CASE WHEN source = 'Purchases' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) = 0, '-', CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN source = 'Purchases' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR)) AS "in",
       IF(SUM(CASE WHEN source = 'Sales' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) = 0, '-', CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN source = 'Sales' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR)) AS "out"
FROM (
  SELECT date, product_id, qty, 'Purchases' AS source
  FROM Purchases
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date, product_id, qty, 'Sales' AS source
  FROM Sales
) AS merged
GROUP BY date, product_id
ORDER BY date, product_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select "date", product_id, qty as "in", cast(null as int) as "out"
from Purchases
union all
select "date", product_id, null, qty
from Sales
order by "date", product_id, "in", "out";
```

You really just need a union. The display with hyphens would be handled by converting the numeric value to a character value and coalescing nulls to whatever you prefer. Generally it's better to do this on the client. You may need to tweak the sort depending on how nulls are handled with your platform.

Answer (score 1):

Based on desired output follow below Query instead of `-` if you need `null's` remove casting and replace `-` with `null`

```
select date, product_id, coalesce(cast(qty as varchar),'-') as 'in', '-' as out
from Purchases
union all
select date, product_id, '-', coalesce(cast(qty as varchar),'-')
from Sales
order by date,'in' desc,out desc
```